# Is it possible to add a progess bar to GAM model in mgcv?

Tags: r, progress-bar, gam, mgcv

I am running a complex GAM model in the MGCV package in R on a big dataset and was wondering if it is possible to compute a progress bar to track how fast it is running rather than waiting with hope.

Would anyone know how to add a progress bar to a model in R?

Comment: I think this is something that has to be built in within the `mgcv::gam` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You can turn on `trace = TRUE` in `gam.control()` which you pass to the `control` argument to `gam` etc.

```r
ctrl <- gam.control(trace = TRUE)
m <- gam(y ~ s(x), data = df, method = 'REML', control = ctrl)
```

Which will at least show you the progress of fitting and some stages of fitting depending on which of `gam()` or `bam()` you are using.

Comment: Thanks for that Gavin, very cool to get an answer off of you!